# Network graph visualization with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph-visualization

I have data that need to be visualize in a network graph. I'm trying to use D3 and I manage to get static graph.

Can anyone suggest me how can I create a graph where when a node, Node A is clicked, it'll expand to other node that is related to Node A.

This is my current code (edit from the example in D3 gallery) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

// http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/
var links = [
  {source: "Plant B", target: "Round shape"},
  {source: "Library", target: "Plant C"},
  {source: "Library", target: "Plant A"},
  {source: "Plant C", target: "Sandy"},
  {source: "Round shape", target: "Plant A"},
  {source: "Plant C", target: "Long shape"},
  {source: "Plant A", target: "Round shape"},
  {source: "Plant D", target: "Lake"},
  {source: "Plant D", target: "Round shape"},
  {source: "Plant A", target: "Library"},
  {source: "Plant B", target: "Library"},
  {source: "Plant E", target: "Lake"},
  {source: "Lake", target: "Sandy"},
  {source: "Plant E", target: "Long shape"},
  {source: "Library", target: "Wet soil"},
  {source: "Library", target: "Plant B"}
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8);

node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function mouseover() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16);
}

function mouseout() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 8);
}

</script>
```

My data is supposed to be from a query actually, so is there any way I can have that node to link to my query page?

Comment: check this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

Comment: @Cyril check that one already. But it doesn't relate the children node to the parent node. My data has nodes that may have relationship with other nodes.

Comment: Ok so in that case you have to design your data into the one expected in the example i am pointing..

Comment: Can the example works with var since my query result will be passed as variable. Thank you for your help. I am very new in this.

Comment: Yeah you can load your content via ajax check https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests  .

Comment: @Cyril do you mean this part?
`var data; // a global
d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {
if (error) return console.warn(error);
data = json;
visualizeit();
});`

Comment: yes this part `var data; // a global d3.json("path/to/file.json", ` where he is loading a json via ajax